# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file (Using two txt files)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm getting this error in my coding and I'm not sure what it means. The code uses different files to compare the 4th column and check if they are the same. I'm very new to coding using Python, I have a week worth of experience. Any help is much appreciated.

```
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from astropy.io import ascii



a = askopenfilename()
b = askopenfilename()

def comp_files(a,b):
    f1 = ascii.read(a)
    f2 = ascii.read(b)
    for r in f1:
        for s in f2:
            if r[3] == s[3]:
                print r[3], s[3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going over its [documentation](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog), `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename` doesn't seem to actually open the file, so you should open it on your own.

```
a = askopenfilename()
b = askopenfilename()

with open(a) as file_a, open(b) as file_b:
    comp_files(file_a, file_b)
```

It is also seems that `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename` expects a dictionary as an argument, so you should verify your usage.